# Difficult limit while trying to use the Continuity Lemma

Tags: probability

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be iid. Uniform$(0,1)$ random variables, and $X_k=k\cdot Y_k$, $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$. Prove that
$$
\frac{S_n}{\left(\frac{n^2}4\right)}\overset w\to1
$$
and
$$
\frac{S_n-\frac{n^2}4}{\frac16n^{\frac32}}\overset w\to\text{Normal}(0,1)
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

I'm pretty stuck on this question. I haven't been able to do either part. My workings for the first part have been like this:

Let $\varphi_A(t)$ be the characteristic function of the random variable $A$. Then
$$
\varphi_{Y_k}(t)=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}.
$$
So now we have that
$$
\varphi_{X_k}(t)=\varphi_{Y_k}(kt)=\frac{e^{ikt}-1}{ikt}.
$$
We now have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{S_n}(t)&=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itS_n}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{it\sum_{k=1}^nX_k}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{k=1}^ne^{itX_k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left(e^{itX_k}\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\varphi_{X_k}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{ikt}-1}{ikt}.
\end{align*}
$$
I think these workings so far are correct, but I'm not 100% sure. And then it comes to the next part where I would expect that the characteristic function of $\varphi_{S_n}\left(\frac{4t}{n^2}\right)$ to converge to the characteristic funtion of the random variable $1$. That is, I would expect $\varphi_{S_n}\left(\frac{4t}{n^2}\right)\to e^{it}$ as $n\to\infty$. However, this limit does not seem easy to calculate, and I don't really have an intuition for whether it is true, which makes me think that maybe characteristic functions and the Continuity Lemma is the wrong approach to use in this case (or I have made a catastrophic error). To complete this method, I would have to show that
$$
\varphi_{S_n}\left(\frac{4t}{n^2}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{e^\frac{4ikt}{n^2}-1}{\left(\frac{4ikt}{n^2}\right)}\to e^{it}
$$
as $n\to\infty$. This is where I have now been stuck for a while. This limit just seems too complicated. Is there a simpler method of doing this? Or is this the simplest way and maybe I am missing a trick with this limit? I think maybe it is possible to work out this limit by using taylor expansions and approximations, but I'm really unsure at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\varphi_{S_n}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{ikt}-1}{ikt}=\prod_{k=1}^n \exp{\left(\frac{ikt}{2}\right)}\,{\rm sinc} \left(\frac{kt}{2}\right)
$$

[where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)  ${\rm sinc} (x)=\sin(x)/x$. Further

$$\varphi_{S_n}\left(\frac{4t}{n^2}\right)=
\prod_{k=1}^n \exp{\left(\frac{i 2 t }{n^2} k\right)}\,\prod_{k=1}^n{\rm sinc} \left(\frac{2t}{n} \frac{k}{n}\right)$$

Regarding the sinc product, for any fixed $t$
each factor inside goes to $1$ as $n\to \infty$,
and all $k$ (as $k/n \le 1$, hence the argument to the sinc tends to $0$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} { \rm sinc}(x)=1$).

Then the second product tends to $1$, and the full product tends to

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \exp{\left(\frac{i 2 t }{n^2} k\right)}$$

Now, $\prod_{k=1}^n a^k = a^{\sum_{k=1}^n k}=a^{n(n+1)/2}$. Then the above (again, for any fixed $t$ and $n \to \infty$) is

$$  \exp{\left( \frac{i 2 t }{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)} \to e^{i t } $$

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks for that intuition. I'm relieved that this at least makes sense to me. I was seriously doubting myself before seeing this. I still don't know exactly how I would rigorously show the step to arrive at $\prod_{k=1}^n\exp\left(\frac{2it}{n^2}k\right)$ though. I think I lack talent for complicated limits haha.

Comment: @WillHarris Actually, I think that after the few editions I made, it's pretty rigorous now.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind if I ask how you came up with the idea to split the limit into a a $\exp$ and a $\text{sinc}$ part?

Comment: It's well known that the Fourier transform of an even rectangle is a sinc function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function  The complex exponential corresponds just to a traslation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Translation_/_time_shifting

Comment: I was just thinking about this answer, and I was wondering something. How can we say that $\prod_{k=1}^n\text{sinc}\left(\frac{2t}n\frac kn\right)$ goes to 1, just because $\text{sinc}\left(\frac{2t}n\frac kn\right)$ goes to 1? Is it known that if a sequence $f_n\to1$, then $\prod_{k=1}^nf_n\to1$?

Comment: @WillHarris : Good point. You question is equivalent to "Given that, for any $k$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n,k} =0$, does this imply $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k} = 0$ ? The answer of course is no. Hence my answer needs some correction.